# How to create Terraform so AWS lambda can pgp encrypt data once added to S3

Tags: lambda, terraform, pgp

I'm trying to convert serverless AWS CFT code to Terraform. The example I'm using is from [bmalnad][1]

`Functionality` - This serverless app converts your data when uploaded to S3 to pgp encrypted format and uploads back to the same S3 bucket.

My terraform code

```
        terraform {
      required_providers {
        aws = {
          source = "hashicorp/aws"
        }
      }
    }

    provider "aws" {
      region = "us-east-1"
    }

    resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
      name = "iam_for_lambda_role"

      assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Effect": "Allow"
        }
      ]
    }
    EOF
    }

    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "terraform_lambda_iam_policy_basic_execution" {
      role       = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.id}"
      policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
    }

    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "s3access" {
      role       = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.id}"
      policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.replication.arn
    }

    resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
      statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
      action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      function_name = aws_lambda_function.example.arn
      principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      source_arn    = aws_s3_bucket.sourceBucket.arn
    }

    resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sourceBucket" {
      bucket = "my-bucket"
  
    }

    resource "aws_iam_policy" "replication" {
      name = "my-policy"
      policy = <<POLICY
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                  "s3:*"
                ],
                "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.sourceBucket.arn}"
            }
      ]
    }
    POLICY
    }

    resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notifications" {
      bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sourceBucket.id

      lambda_function {
        lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.example.arn
        events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
      }
      depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket]
    }
```

The lambda resource

```
    resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
      function_name = "ServerlessExample"

      s3_bucket = "awsserverlessrepo-changesets-plntc6bfnfj"
      s3_key    = "<account_number>/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:485061371590:applications-s3-pgp-encryptor-versions-1.0.7/52a793a0-15da-42ae-a04e-abe5b25ba562"
      handler = "handler.encrypt"
      runtime = "nodejs10.x"
      timeout = "30"
      memory_size = "1024"
      role = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn

      tracing_config {
        mode = "Active"
      }

      environment {
        variables = {
          BASE64ENCODEDPUBLICKEY = "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*************************************"
          sourceBucketName = aws_s3_bucket.sourceBucket.arn
        }
      }
    }
```

I see when I add any file to the S3 bucket the PGP encryption lambda is getting invoked. It results in an error below

```
    START RequestId: xyz123-54e8-43b2-b7be-f611e24b5cb6 Version: $LATEST
    INFO    lambda fired - raw.txt
    INFO    unencrypted file - processing
    INFO    successfully read file
    ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {
        "errorType": "TypeError",
        "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'Body' of null",
        "code": "TypeError",
        "message": "Cannot read property 'Body' of null",
        "time": "2021-03-03T21:18:54.003Z",
        "stack": [
            "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Body' of null",
            "    at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/handler.js:21:41)",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:369:18)",
            "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
            "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
            "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
            "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
            "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
            "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)"
        ]
    }
```

I do not want to use `resource "aws_cloudformation_stack"` and call the example CFT from above, it works. I need to make this working in terraform stand alone.
[1]: https://github.com/bmalnad/s3-pgp-encryptor

Comment: If the error is from lambda itself, you would have to show its code and where the error occurs.

Comment: Here is the code https://github.com/bmalnad/s3-pgp-encryptor/blob/master/handler.js